# Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processor Installation failed

Tags: android-studio, sdk, hyper-v, android-sdk-tools, amd-processor

I am attempting to install the Android Emulator for Android Studio and every time I attempt it it asks to install another add on in order to install it. Immediately after it fails. I have enable virtualization in the BIOS, I have disabled hyper-V, hypervisor platform, virtual machine and device guard. The error message is:

```
[SC] StartService FAILED with error 4294967201.
Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installation failed. To install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors
```

If anyone has any suggestions it will be much appreciated as I have spent a lot of time trying to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem until just now, found the answers here: https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors/issues/17.

Some anti-virus programs have a feature that blocks some virtualization functionality to protect against malware that uses said functionality. All you need to do is disable the feature and restart your PC.
For me, it was Avast that created the Problem.
I hope I could help you, although this thread is a month old.

Comment: The posted link solved it. TLDR; Virtualisation Technology wasn't enabled in my BIOS/UEFI ‍♂️